# Dividing long by long returns 0

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate % of used diskspace in Windows and totaldrive denotes total diskspace of c drive in Long and freedrive dentoes free space in Long.

```
 long totaloccupied = totaldrive - freedrive;
```

Here calculating % of usage

```
 Long Percentageused =(totaloccupied/totaldrive*100);
 System.out.println(Percentageused);
```

The print statement returns 0. Can someone help as I am not getting the desired value

Comment: Heh. It was a long day that I enjoyed a float down the river...

Comment: Why are you using `Long` instead of `long`? Also, please look at Java naming conventions for `percentageUsed`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You are probably dividing a long with a long, which refers to (long/long = long) operation, giving a long result (in your case 0).

You can achieve the same thing by casting either operand of the division to a float type.

```
Long Percentageused = (long)((float)totaloccupied/totaldrive*100);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are doing integer division! Since `totaloccupied` is smaller than `totaldrive`, the division of both gives the answer `0`. You should convert to double first:

```
double percentageUsed = 100.0 * totalOccupied / totalDrive;
```

Note that adding the decimal point to the `100` ensures it is treated as a `double`.

Comment: if totalOccupied and totalDrive both are long, then even multiplying by 100.0 will result in 0.0

Answer (score 1):

That will be evaluated left to right, the first integer division will return 0 (e.g. 8/10 evaluates to 0). Either convert values to floats or do 100*a/b. Floats will give you a more precise result.

Comment: `float` will *not* give a more precise result if the numbers involved are large.

Comment: It will if you do (float)(100*a)/(float)b. The two sides will differ by a relatively small order of magnitude, which is where most precision loss occurs.

Comment: BTW, whoever came through and down voted every answer here, please leave a constructive comment.

Comment: If the objective is an integer percentage, the 100*a/b solution, with a and b both long, would work well. Float or double is only needed to get answers like "85.5%".